# str.IndexOf fails on string combination separated by "space"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript function which goes like this. I can see that the words are side by side separated by space in document. Any idea why this is failing?

```js
var txt = $("tr.trofinterest:first").text().toUpperCase(); //even triedgetting rid of whitespace characters
//.replace("  ", " ").replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ")

//and various combination of regex but the function below fails
if (txt.indexOf("TWO WORDS") >= 0) {
  // do sth here //but this is returned false
  console.log("Found TWO WORDS together");
}
//But the folloing statement returns true in all cases
if (txt.indexOf("TWO") >= 0 && txt.indexOf("WORDS") >= 0) {
  console.log("words exist in sentence and i can see they are side by side seperated by space")
}
console.log(txt); //this prints "This tr has text with Two Words which are interesting and the words are side by side"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <!-- nested child tables with a -->
  <tr class='trofinterest'>
    <td>This tr has text with Two Words which are interesting and the words are side by side</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just because a string contains `"TWO"` and also contains `"WORDS"`, that doesn't mean it contains `"TWO WORDS"`. It could contain `"TWO MUMBLE MUMBLE WORDS"`, or `"WORDS TWO"`, or `"TWO\nWORDS"`, or `"TWO<space><space>WORDS"` (surprisingly, comment formatting made the literal version of that look like it had only one space), or...

Comment: They are side by side in the order "TWO WORDS" in console.log(txt)

Comment: Can you also verify that character is normal space, not some Unicode character, apart from 1st comment?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can't believe I got to the end of that comment without seeing `"TWORDS"` :)

Comment: @FloodGravemind - Look at the actual text, you'll find that what's between `"TWO"` and `"WORDS"` is not a single space character. Perhaps it's two or three. Perhaps it's a newline. Or a non-breaking space. Or...

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I'm just not that clever. ;-)

Comment: @JamesThorpe I actually tried combinations of regex to filter whitespaces

Comment: Also note that `indexof()` is not the same as `indexOf()`. I assume this is just an error in the question as you state you get an output in the console, which you wouldn't if that error existed in your local copy.

Comment: For your shown code `txt.indexOf("TWO WORDS") >= 0` evaluates to `true`, so the body of that if containing `// do sth here //but this is returned false` is executed, placing a `console.log('two words')` at the place of that comment will result in that log being printed in the console.

Comment: @Teemu its just a shorthand you can substitue it with "tr#"

Comment: Something wrong with jsFiddle actually ...

Comment: Please update the question with a [mcve]. As you can see, the snippet there right now works just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So basically whitespace characters ere messing with the string and Firefox would not show the string exactly

I had to first convert "spaces" to '+' using

```
txt = txt.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '+'); 
// this gives better visual represntation of the problem
do {
 txt = txt.replace("++", '+'); filter out mutiples to single
   }
while (txt.indexOf("++") >= 0);
if(txt.indexOf("TWO+WORDS")>=0){
console.log("Hey! Hey! Ho! Ho! Not cloning your grandpa has got to go!!!")
}
```

Edit for down voting. I am only interested in `"TWO+WORDS"` not the entire string. Infact its better if TWO+WORDS is in original string. Sometimes no need to over engineer a solution. Anyway my answer provides a method to figure out the problem. First steps in finding a solution.

Comment: Such kind of hacks lead to a really bad _"solution"_. What if the text will contain a `+` in the future? And what if the reason for the failure is just shadowed by that approach and will reappear when the text changes within the `td`?

Comment: I am only interested in "TWO+WORDS" not the entire string. Infact its better if TWO+WORDS is in original string. Sometimes no need to ovethink a problem.

Comment: If your shown code works for you, then it would also work if you use `.replace(/\s/g, ' ')` and do  `do { txt = txt.replace("  ", ' ');  } while (txt.indexOf("  ") >= 0);` or even get rid of the do while and use `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')`. But replacing the space with a `+` to find `TWO WORDS` is a really error prone way to _"solve"_ the problem.

Comment: @t.niese What if tou encounter "TWO&nbspWords" there is never a perfect solution for strings. You will need a full fledge word processing/dictionary program to ever achieve such a solution which is a overkill for problem i need to solve. Even Visual Studio gets string and character formatting wrong sometimes.

Comment: If the solution you show here is able to deal with `TWO&nbspWords` then `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` and `txt.indexOf("TWO WORDS")` would work too. If your solution does not work with `TWO&nbspWords`  then what's the benefit of yours over `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')`?

Comment: @t.niese The benefit for me is "+" is better than WHITESPACE when it comes to visually analysing the string. So I can deduct WHITESPACES that I have missed in my code.

Comment: `visually analyzing the string` is a requirement you brought up right now. Your question is that you want to find `TWO` followed by `WORDS` only separated by spaces and that this does not work for you. And to solve that problem (not the visually analyzing part) should not be solved with your approach. You are for sure free to still go with that approach.

Comment: @t.niese I am visually analysing to see what whitespaces I have missed to narrow down the problem in my code. I am sure you console.log() your scripts when debugging.